# Looking for a Drawing Program

Tags: reference-request, math-software

I am writing a math exam and I'd like to include a picture.  I want a free drawing program so that I can draw the coordinate axes with a unit circle.  Inscribed in the unit circle will be a hexagon.  The interior of the hexagon will be divided into triangles.  Which drawing program will make this process as painless as possible?

Comment: [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/)

Comment: See also [Software for drawing geometry diagrams](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985/72) (many of the suggestions there would work for much more than just geometry diagrams).

Comment: For general-purpose drawing, I use Inkscape.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see a good list at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_interactive_geometry_software).

I suggest you try GeoGebra, which is convenient for geometric constructions (for more general things, Inkscape is very good).

Comment: A very good wiki to share, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention nowhere that your program has to include a GUI, TikZ is always mentionable (although I know that if this is just a quick assignment for an exam, even using LaTeX might seem like overkill).

You can look at the official documentation here: [paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf)

and some different examples here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Answer (score 1):

I use [ipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipe_%28program%29) for all my figures. Snapping, vector graphics, and the ability to include latex are some of the standout features.