# Draw online polygon/triangle

Tags: geometry, math-software, online-resources

Is there is any website where I can draw a polygon/triangle online. A website with an option to use coordinates to plot points and other tools to draw polygons.

Comment: All you left is choose: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams

Comment: any online site?

Comment: Thanks. http://livegeometry.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use The Geogebra Interactive Module [here](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing) .

Comment: Thanks. But http://livegeometry.com/ is awesome

Comment: @user960567 I guess that it is always good to have multiple choices...

Comment: @pedja dead link :(

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr if I can install *Microsoft Silverlight*, then I can view the link.