# A program to draw simple geometry (points, lines, dotted lines etc.)

Tags: geometry, math-software

I am looking for a program to create images of very simple situations, e.g. [this](http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/yslhgkoz/geom.jpg). I have already tried Geogebra but I am not quite satisfied with the result. I want my images to look as if they were taken from some (geometry) book; this is what I mean:

[image]

This was taken from my last year's geometry lecture notes. I feel like everyone is using the same program to create such images (because they all look the same).

Does anyone know what program I could use in order to create such images? I'm sure I could succeed with both MS Paint and Adobe Photoshop, but I'm looking for some program made to create such images. I hope this is the right place to ask for this and thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: If you don't mind coding, [JSXGraph](http://www.jsxgraph.org/) is nice.

Comment: A related question: [Software for drawing geometry diagrams](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10136/integrate-coding-into-the-geometry-curriculum/10263#10263

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do not like coding and looking for WYIWYG, then [Ipe](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/) is a good option.

If you like coding, then you have many options: [PSTricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/), [TIKZ/PGF](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/), ...

Comment: +1, coding also gives more control that will not be available with WYSWYG

Comment: Ipe is exactly what I've been looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You may want to try Tikz. See http://www.texample.net/tikz/ for examples.

Comment: I am using Tikz with LaTex on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I mostly use GeoGebra but, that TikZ also seems quite convenient indeed. I wonder if it works on Windows as well...? I mean, a "compiled" or a "ready to compile" version for example. Is the source code of TikZ available by the way?

Answer (score 6):

I use [Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) for the Mac. It is by far the easiest figure-maker for mathematics and is LaTeX friendly. Simply drag and drop predefined shapes (including points, lines, polygons, etc.) within Omigraffle, adjust them as needed for size, opacity, color, etc., use [LaTeXIt](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php) to add labels or equations, save, then export to pdf or eps. I created the following faithful reproduction of your image by sight in 45 seconds.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I forgot to mention that I'm looking for a program which I can run on Windows 7.

Comment: You can run LaTex on Windows.

Comment: Any vector graphics program should suffice.

Answer (score 5):

You might also try out [DrGeo](http://www.drgeo.eu/) which is a interactive geometry program.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Screenshot 1 source: http://screenshots.debian.net/screenshots/d/drgeo/2090_large.png

Screenshot 2 source: http://blog.ofset.org/public/drgeo/DrGeoII-2cercles.png

Comment: Seems quite fun and usuful, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

I have been enjoying [kseg](http://www.mit.edu/~ibaran/kseg.html). It is very quick to draw diagrams in `kseg`.

After you draw the diagram you can drag the components around and the others will follow, retaining the same constraints. For example, in this diagram it appears that $NM$ is the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$:

[image: example diagram]

And I can see if that still appears to be the case even after I move point $C$ to make a very different inscribed quadrilateral:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[Euklides](http://www.eukleides.org/) produces pretty nice geometry sketch.

[image: Feuerbach's Circle]

Answer (score 0):

[Crealesson](https://crealesson.com/) feels like a blackboard drawings as multi-board something like power-point. produces small videos without any additional software.
[image]