# Software for drawing braid-related graphs

Tags: soft-question, math-software, geometric-topology, knot-theory, braid-groups

I am looking for a (preferably free) software that can draw braid-related graphs, such as [image] and [image]

(Quoted from **A Study of Braids** By Kunio Murasugi, B. Kurpita)

I have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams), but the answers given seem not very helpful for my case; for example, I found it not so easy to draw a cube or a braid in Geogebra. Also, I can draw braids with the braid package as is explained [here](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/09/the-braids-package/),

(for example, something like [image])

but I don't know how to modify the graphs so that it looks like the pictures above. Also, how about braids with $n$ strands for a general $n$, such as [image]?

Comment: What about TikZ? I know its not a drawing software, but its free and once you have learned it you can "draw" everything!

Comment: You would have a much higher chance of someone responding with great help on the TeX stack exchange (I've asked TikZ/PGF questions there myself and have always gotten back answer(s)).

Comment: You could use a program like Adobe Illustrator, although it's not free. I've done that with many of my papers. (I've been using TikZ more in recent years since it is a native TeX thing.)

Comment: Maybe you can ask in the [Geogebra Forum](http://www.geogebra.org/) whether [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) may help here. Look for example at [this applet](http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m259193) of drawing knots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/de/) a lot for my thesis, which has a [path effect for drawing knots](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kxnHQAo6Sc). It is - at least in the version I have - extremely buggy, but if you never ever change the path while the knot effect is turned on, it works :)