# What software can draw all pictures for Trigonometric expressions like this?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[I am preparing these pictures manually for Structural designs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xn7o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqDSN.png)

I want some software which will automatically generate all these possible pictures from the given Trigonometric Expression written in algebraic form like in text books

If that kind of software or Theory is available why will i reinvent the wheel?
I call this GeometrifyingTrigonometry,I search with Pictorial Trigonometry , I search with Pictorial Proof.Nothing found in internet

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `alternative-proof`? Or with `proof-theory`?

Comment: Thank you Jose Carlos Santos for your interest in this .I actually dont know which subject it belongs.I need pictorial proofs of Trigonometric Identities or Trigonometric Expressions.Normally we get Algebraic Step wise proofs of Trigonometric Expressions or For Trigonometric Identities.I was trying to write my own program , but that will take time(https://github.com/SanjoyNath/GeometrifyingTrigonometry/wiki) So i was searching this to get my works done faster if such things are already there.

Comment: You could look at some already existing posts on the site, for example: [Software for drawing geometry diagrams](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985) (and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1985)). A few such posts are also listed here: [Graphing Software - a faq?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2845)

Comment: Fantastic Lisp is found here https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-lisp-autolisp-and-general/is-there-any-lisp-routine-to-align-a-particular-line-segment-of/m-p/8506092/highlight/false#M379167            Autocad is good proof engine if good programming is done.Geometrifying Trigonometry will now work

Answer (score -1):

There are many Software for drawing geometry diagrams/pictures , but for specific type of diagrams/pictures have to generate programming...Like

[Geometrifying Trigonometry NARRAYS Debashis Bhunia(C)](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/thanks-to-autocad-for-geometrifying-trigonometry-narrays-c/td-p/8540134)

[Geometrifying Trigonometry NARRAYS Debashis Bhunia(C)](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-lisp-autolisp-and-general/geometrifying-trigonometry-narrays-scale-down-issue/m-p/8522807#M379498)

Comment: Thank You very much Debashis Bhunia. Now we are more confident that Geometrifying Trigonometry(C) will search the most optimum TRUSS arrangement for given loading conditions in one single formulation of load path.Our hassles for multi iterative Heuristic search for optimum arrangement will reduce to single deterministic frameworks.Same will help in other optimization problems through thousands of new theorems of Geometrifying Trigonometry(C).