# What software is used to draw mathematical shapes in books like this one?

Tags: math-software

What software is used to draw mathematical shapes in books like this one?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Repeated question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/software-for-drawing-geometry-diagrams

Comment: This question may also be more suitable for the [LaTeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Could you say which book it is and its date of edition ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the book is "Manfredo P. do Carmo - Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces-Dover Publications (2016)"

Answer (score 3):

It is not sure at all it is a computerized drawing!

Some 60 and even 50 years ago, there were graphic designers able to use in a baffling way decals/transfers representing graphic items such as geometrical shapes, arrows etc. + of course scissors and glue to give a first figure.

Then this figure was photographed, and it is (a generally resized version of) this photography that was inserted into the text.

See [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62028/how-were-scientific-illustrations-made-before-the-spread-of-digital-computers) or [there](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/23548) for example.