# Software for drawing math figures like this

Tags: math-software

What software is used to draw this?

[image]

Comment: Probably TikZ can be used (with a TeX distribution).

Comment: You can do almost the same figure with GeoGebra.

Comment: See this [old link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1985/305862)